# Where was Diana during the events of Man of Steel?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, man-of-steel

Out-of-universe, when they made *Man of Steel*, DC weren't planning to pursue an expanded universe in the same way Marvel had, so *Man of Steel* was made as its own standalone film. When it turned out to be quite successful, it sparked the DCEU and Warner Bros started work on BvS. So the fact that Diana never showed up or helped out either when Clark crashed to Earth or when super-powered aliens invaded the planet is totally understandable OoU, because at the time it wasn't an Extended Universe.

However, I was wondering if, since Warner Bros have now opted to make the DCEU, there has been any reference or explanation as to what Diana's been up to since 1918?

Comment: Seeing as how the entire course of the alien invasion happen in a couple of days, IIRC, it's entirely plausible that she was just out of contact during that time.  Maybe visiting mom on Themyscira.

Comment: Oh, she was out there, [you just couldn't see her](https://pics.me.me/well-played-air-force-ell-played-brilliant-23560734.png)

Comment: Is she psychic?  When would she have gone where?  We find Diana employed in Paris.  In BvS she flies commercial.  If she hopped on a plane the instant the Battle of Smallville hit the news, she'd arrive 16 hours later, long after the Black Zero Event in Metropolis already wrapped up.  If she responded to the BZE, she'd get there 9 hours later.  That's IF flights aren't diverted from Metropolis due to the battle!

Comment: Noting that *[Wonder Woman 1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman_1984)* indicates that Diana is still operating in the world of men, performing heroics in a not-terribly-discreet fashion.

Answer (score 20):

The only reference that she has made is a vague statement she makes in *Dawn of Justice*:

> A hundred years ago I walked away from mankind. From a century of horrors. Man made a world where standing together is impossible.

Given the timing, this would mean that Diana "walked away" from mankind almost immediately after the end of World War I. We can only speculate why: it could be the loss of Steve Trevor, her disillusionment that nothing changed after killing Ares, etc. We'll likely find out more in *Wonder Woman 2* if/when it comes out.

Diana only comes out of "hiding" when she learns that Luthor has proof of who she is and wants to get it back. Had she not already been in the city when Doomsday appeared, IMO it's unlikely she would have reappeared as Wonder Woman.

Comment: I wonder if Luthor's surveillance footage was set during _Man of Steel_... Lemme check.

Comment: The timestamps on the footage from Paris show 2015, but I don't remember when _Man of Steel_ was set in-universe.

Comment: I don't know if we got a specific date, but I would expect it was "present day" which would be 2013.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you haven't seen Wonder Woman, but the end of WW certainly gives me the impression that she has been doing WW stuff on the sly for the whole time, which doesn't help answer the original question.

Comment: she may have been doing things "on the sly" wherever she happened to be living, but that's very different from making a public appearance during an alien invasion to help out an entire world she didn't really care about. Part of the final scene in _Dawn of Justice_ was to show Bruce convincing Diana that she needed to come out of hiding for good.

Comment: The DCEU wiki has got a section on this "Century of Horrors" (WWII, Cold War, Revolutions, Genocides, Terrorism, etc) causing her to lose all faith in humanity and basically throw her hands in the air like "Screw it, let them sort their own stuff out", as well as a bit on how she had an encounter with Slipknot at some point because he was a sexist pig. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to cite any references for these, so it's unclear how accurate they are.

Comment: I guess what I'm after are those references, some official source confirming that she's fed up with humanity as a whole and so explicitly chooses not to help them with anything for nearly 100 years. If you can find that, you'll have yourself an accepted answer.